# Problems With Header(Location)

Tags: php, header

I have a problem with my header location. On the first time, the header location works fine,

but, the second time, it doesn't work. I've removed all the spaces and empty rules in the code but I have still the same problem.

First header:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4"> 
    <?php if ($berichtauteur == $_SESSION['sess_user']) {
      ?>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="beantwoord">Markeren als beantwoord </button>
      </form>
      <?php
      if (isset($_POST['beantwoord'])) {
        $updatestatus = "UPDATE forum_subonderwerp SET subonderwerp_status = '1' where subonderwerp_ID=". $subject. ";";
        @mysqli_query ($verbinding, $updatestatus) or die (mysqli_error($verbinding));
        header('Location: http://google.nl');
      }
    }
    ?>
  </div>
```

Second header:

```
            <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" method="post">
          <textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
          <script>CKEDITOR.replace('text');</script>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="plaatsreactie">Plaats reactie </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["plaatsreactie"])) {
      header('Location: http://qooqle.nl');
      $queryinput ="INSERT INTO forum_reacties (reactie_bericht, subonderwerp_ID, reactie_plaatser) VALUES ('".$_POST['text']."', '".$subject."', '".$useridnummer."')";
      @mysqli_query ($verbinding, $queryinput) or die (mysqli_error($verbinding));
    }
    ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: put error_reporting(0) before your code start... it giving you error because might be there some warnings showing before redirection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Both should not work. Outputting any character before calling `header()` is not permitted.

Comment: remove http and kill the script after using header.

Comment: @someone is right, you cannot output HTML before the header()

Comment: @someone Could you explain to me why it works fine at the first?

Comment: @someone Ive changed it to this:

Comment: <?php
        if (isset($_POST["plaatsreactie"])) {
          header('Location: http://qooqle.nl');
          $queryinput ="INSERT INTO forum_reacties (reactie_bericht, subonderwerp_ID, reactie_plaatser) VALUES ('".$_POST['text']."', '".$subject."', '".$useridnummer."')";
          @mysqli_query ($verbinding, $queryinput) or die (mysqli_error($verbinding));
        }
        ?>

Comment: @SandervanHoogdalem as I have said, calling `header()` after outputting any character is not permitted. This includes whitespace(such as space, newline, tab etc.).  So you can't put any character before `<?php` tag or calling `echo` or `print` before calling `header()`. Therefore, your code in your comment should work (regarding the call of (`header()`)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following things at the top so that you can find the reasons for not being working proper.

**1.) Try One:**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

`error_reporting` — Sets which PHP errors are reported

The `error_reporting()` function sets the error_reporting directive at runtime. PHP has many levels of errors, using this function sets that level for the duration (runtime) of your script. If the optional level is not set, error_reporting() will just return the current error reporting level.

**2.) Try Two:**

Try placing the ob_start() at the top before redirection occurs.

`ob_start` — Turn on output buffering

> And in the second header you have to replace the redirection location

Replace:

```
 header('Location: http://qooqle.nl');
```

with

```
 header('Location: google.nl');
```

Comment: thank you so much it works now, I placed the ob_start() and it works.

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `http://qooqle.nl` instead of `google.nl` in your seond header. 
I don't know if you have put that in purpose..